# how do i add sqlite browser in eclipse?

Tags: android

I have already SQLite manager in the file explorer but here I can view only database structure and browse data means see data of table and I can not insert ,delete and update data. so I want do CRUD operation for database table. Can i add
SQLite browser in eslipse?.

Please Can anybody suggest me.

Thanking you

Comment: SQLite add ons for the firefox and chrome are available on internet. you can directly edit data by double click on browse data.

Comment: OK fine, now i have SQLite in Firefox but when i will insert,update data from my apps that time how that data will store in SQLite which is in Firefox. can you give me a detail.

Answer (score 0):

You have to paste the db file into assets folder. Then you can able to do CRUD operation:)